# Building a map from a vector

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

So I have a vector which sort of looks like this

```
["John" 23 "5551234" "Sally" 34 "5556667"]
```

the vector contains a lot more entries like this, what I am trying to do is make a vector of maps like this:

```
[{:name "John" :age 23 :ph "5551234"} {:name "Sally" :age 34 :ph "5556667"}]
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: How are you getting your records? That is are you reading them as delimited data, or are you constructing them as shown?

Comment: I'm scraping them off a website

Comment: Thanks. I figured you were not getting the records in a delimited form.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
(def sample ["John" 23 "5551234" "Sally" 34 "5556667" "Harry" 42 "5554242"])
```

Partition the input vector into records using e.g. `(partition 3 sample)` (each record has 3 elements) and then

Map a zipmap:

```
(mapv #(zipmap [:name :age :ph] %) (partition 3 sample))
; => [{:ph "5551234", :age 23, :name "John"} 
;     {:ph "5556667", :age 34, :name "Sally"}
;     {:ph "5554242", :age 42, :name "Harry"}]
```

Or use `for` comprehension (returns a lazy sequence rather than a vector):

```
(for [[name age ph] (partition 3 sample)] {:name name :age age :ph ph})
; => ({:name "John", :age 23, :ph "5551234"} 
      {:name "Sally", :age 34, :ph "5556667"} 
      {:name "Harry", :age 42, :ph "5554242"})
```

Note key order is not defined for maps. The `for` comphrehension is using an array-map since the number of key-value pairs is small, and thus the keys appear in order, but this is an implementation detail. You can explicitly use array-maps if order is important but will have a performance penalty for look-ups on larger maps.

Comment: It's mixing up the key orders, though I think the problem lies in my datasource

Comment: @Jeroko Key order is not defined for hash-maps.

Answer (score 0):

Another couple options:

```
(->> ["John" 23 "5551234" "Sally" 34 "5556667"]
     (partition 3)
     (map (fn [[name age ph]]
            {:name name :age age :ph ph})))

(->> ["John" 23 "5551234" "Sally" 34 "5556667"]
     (partition 3)
     (map (partial interleave [:name :age :ph]))
     (map (partial apply hash-map)))
```